# Let $r \in \Bbb R$ be such that $0 < r < 1$. Prove that the series $r^2 + r + r^4 + r^3 + ... + r^{2n} + r^{2n-1} + ...$ converges or diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Let $r \in \Bbb R$ be such that $0 < r < 1$. Prove that the series

$r^2 + r + r^4 + r^3 + ... + r^{2n} + r^{2n-1} + ...$

converges or diverges.

I know $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n$ converges to $\frac{1}{1-r}$ for $|r| <1$. I'd like to rearrange the series above to be written as

$r + r^2 + r^3 + r^4 +...+ r^{2n-1} + r^{2n} + ...$

Is that all I would need to prove the series in question converges? Compare it to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n$ beginning at $n = 1$ instead of $n = 0$ ?

Comment: In what kind of series, rearrangement make the sum of series unchanged?

Comment: It's important to note that the geometric series is absolutely convergent, so we can rearrange the terms of the sum.

Comment: Thank you to both, I knew there was an important piece I missed somewhere. Other than that, my logic is fine?

Comment: If the series is "absolutely convergent" it will converge if you swap the order of the terms (not the case if it is "conditionally convergent").  If a geometric series is converges it is absolutely convergent.